# Facebook like view does not work on some Android versions

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am developing an Android app which has Facebook like view implemented. I managed to follow the tutorials and integrated the sdk in my Studio project.
(I referred https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/like-button).
According to the FB flow, when you click on the like view, it opens the Facebook activity, which previews the URL you are liking. On this page, you can Unlike, share the URL or go back to your activity.
I am able to achieve this, but the functionality works fine only for Android OS 5.x
When I run the app on Android 4.4 or 6.x, the Facebook activity opens up, shows a blank screen and closes itself, without liking the page.
Am I missing something here, which might be specific to OS, like a permission? because I presume if this is working on even 1 OS, then the implementation of this should be fine.

Thank you for the help.

My manifest:

```
    <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider140xxxxxxxxx518"
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:exported="true"/>

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

My activity's onCreate:

```
LikeView like_view = (LikeView) findViewById(R.id.like_view);
like_view.setLikeViewStyle(LikeView.Style.STANDARD);
        like_view.setAuxiliaryViewPosition(LikeView.AuxiliaryViewPosition.INLINE);
like_view.setObjectIdAndType("https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/like-button", LikeView.ObjectType.UNKNOWN);
```

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]. Figured out the problem. The app being in sandbox mode, can be "tested" only by the users which are mentioned under roles.
Co-incidentally, the user which had the permission was on the device running 5.x, which made me think that this issue is related to OS version.
To add the user as a tester, go to the FB app on developers.facebook.com and add the email / user / fbid under the Roles section.